# How to use long SQL Query in .jsp Pages good format?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jsp

I have long query for showing league standing table. It’s is to long and I want to use is without create view in database.

What format should I write in a long line, not in a single line, but in lines one after the other?

Is there any solution exist for it? Or how can I write this query in .jsp file as it is (not like in one row). Because it’s hard to manage it. Normally, I tried to use “+ every row ends but query gives error. Is there any solution for that? or If you provide any example for how to use long sql query in .jsp file will be much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

My query is below:

```
SELECT 
    `t`.`team_id` AS `team_id`,
    `t`.`team_logo` AS `team_logo`,
    `t`.`league_id` AS `league_id`,
    `t`.`team_name` AS `Team`,
    SUM(`tot`.`P`) AS `P`,
    SUM(`tot`.`W`) AS `W`,
    SUM(`tot`.`D`) AS `D`,
    SUM(`tot`.`L`) AS `L`,
    SUM(`tot`.`F`) AS `F`,
    SUM(`tot`.`A`) AS `A`,
    SUM(`tot`.`GD`) AS `GD`,
    SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) AS `Pts`
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        `matches`.`home_team_id` AS `Team`,
            1 AS `P`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` > `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `W`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` = `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `D`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` < `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `L`,
            `matches`.`home_score` AS `F`,
            `matches`.`home_score` AS `A`,
            (`matches`.`home_score` - `matches`.`away_score`) AS `GD`,
            (CASE
                WHEN (`matches`.`home_score` > `matches`.`away_score`) THEN 3
                WHEN (`matches`.`home_score` = `matches`.`away_score`) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS `PTS`
    FROM
        `matches` UNION ALL SELECT 
        `matches`.`away_team_id` AS `away_team_id`,
            1 AS `1`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` < `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `IF(home_score < away_score,1,0)`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` = `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `IF(home_score = away_score,1,0)`,
            IF((`matches`.`home_score` > `matches`.`away_score`), 1, 0) AS `IF(home_score > away_score,1,0)`,
            `matches`.`away_score` AS `away_score`,
            `matches`.`home_score` AS `home_score`,
            (`matches`.`away_score` - `matches`.`home_score`) AS `GD`,
            (CASE
                WHEN (`matches`.`home_score` < `matches`.`away_score`) THEN 3
                WHEN (`matches`.`home_score` = `matches`.`away_score`) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS `CASE WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`
    FROM
        `matches`) `tot`
    JOIN `teams` `t` ON ((`tot`.`Team` = `t`.`team_id`)))
WHERE
    (`t`.`league_id` = 1)
GROUP BY `tot`.`Team`
ORDER BY SUM(`tot`.`PTS`) DESC;
```

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nathan_Sav, but I knew to how to create and use view. I need to long sql formatting how to use in .jsp file.

Comment: Could your long SQL be the view and use jsp to query the view?

Comment: yes, I only need how to format in tsp because when I copied and pasted gives error. I want to write row by row above query into tsp file.